# Which Stack Exchange sites show a banner for the 2019 Developer Survey?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I just had a bunch of different Stack Exchange sites open, and I noticed that some but not all of them had a banner inviting me to take the 2019 Developer Survey. Not even all sites in the [Technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) section, even though the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/23/our-2019-developer-survey-is-open-to-coders-everywhere) says:

> The survey is expected to close on February 12th. If you’re a registered user who completes the survey in its entirety, you have the option to get the Census badge on **Stack Overflow or a different technical site** in the Stack Exchange network.

(emphasis mine).

I understand that it doesn't make sense to show the (English) survey on [foreign](https://es.stackoverflow.com) [Stack](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) [Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) [sites](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), but I was rather surprised to see the banner on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) which explicitly forbids development questions and not on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) (it has still a beta theme, that might be the cause).

I can write a script to compile a list of sites where the banner is shown, but

1. <s>I'm lazy</s>
2. <s>I have to pack for a skiing holiday</s>
3. <s>I want to know the reasoning behind which sites were selected</s>
4. All of the above

Follow-up question: does the list of sites where the banner is shown coincide with the list of sites where you can get the Census badge?

Comment: Hmm, might be queryable then on SEDE by sunday to look for the census badge. But I'm with your number 1. ...

Comment: I'd do that on Sunday but for reason 2...

Comment: I'll put the query together tomorrow. i need some sleep first

Comment: I think you can wait - the survey hasn't been up since last Sunday. Or has it?

Comment: Yeah, I can look for the badges awarded last year and then see what got added in 2019. Will keep me occupied over the weekend

Comment: I've checked some top users returned by [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Census) and it seems they've been awarded in the past on (*.)SO only.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Census badge [has been permanently retired and retroactively revoked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/removal-of-the-census-badge) from all users on all sites.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the Census badge has been retired, but what about the banner?

Comment: Does this same banner still show up? Can someone run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiosity got the better of me and I wrote a [small script](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/5641848ce10fd2687dd98554160b4055) to investigate. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/db7fa875e0799de016a7d9f2809c0766) are the results. 
The following sites show the banner and have the Census badge:

- [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com)
- [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com)
- [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)
- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com)
- [Android Enthusiats](https://android.stackexchange.com)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

The foreign Stack Overflow sites have the Census badge but not (at the moment) the announcement banner.

I'm still looking for an (official) answer how these sites have been selected. *pictures Shog9 throwing darts at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid*